# The javascript code for cookie acceptance is correct but does not work, instead there is a strange error

Tags: javascript, cookies

The javascript code for cookie acceptance is ok but not working, instead I find this console error :

> The use of drawWindow method of CanvasRenderingContext2D is deprecated. Use the tabs.captureTab API for extensions instead https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/captureTab pagedata-script.js:1:12465

I don't know where or why it comes from but my javascript code does not run.

If someone has an idea.
Here is the code below :

HTML

```
<div id="consent-popup" class="hidden dark">
    <img src="_images/cookie.png"/>
    <p>By using this site, you agree to our <a href="#">Terms of Service</a>.<br>
Please <a id="accept" href="#">Accept</a> before using the site.
    </p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#consent-popup {
  position: fixed;
  display: inline-flex;
  bottom: 3.5rem;
  right: 0;
  padding: 25px 5% 25px 25px;
  width: 40vw;
  box-shadow: -2px 5px 10px 5px #19233e;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
#consent-popup.hidden {
  transform: translate(100%, 0);
  opacity: 0;
}
#consent-popup > img {
  margin: 0 25px 0 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
#consent-popup > p {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: ArialLight;
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: #000000;
  text-align: left;
}
#consent-popup > p > a {
  color: #dbdce8;
}
```

Javascript

```
//accept_cookies.js
function getCookie(cname) {
    let name = cname + "=";
    let ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(let i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        let c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}

function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays){
    const d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    let expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/;SameSite=None;secure=" + true + ";";
}

function isAccept(cname){
    //console.log(getCookie(cname));
    if(getCookie(cname) == "true"){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}

window.onload = () => {
    function acceptFn(){
        setCookie("abc_consent", true, 7);
        consentPopup.classList.add('hidden');
    }
    const consentPopup = document.getElementById('consent-popup');
    const acceptBtn = document.getElementById('accept');
    acceptBtn.addEventListener('click', acceptFn);

    if (!isAccept("bdc_consent")) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            consentPopup.classList.remove('hidden');
        }, 2000);
    }

};
```

The only external scripts are those of bootstrap and ajax googleapis:

"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"
"https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"

Thanks.

Comment: Please only add tags that are relevant to the issue. This doesn't seem to have anything to do with PHP or CSS. Looking at the warning (it seems to be a deprecation warning, not an error), it seems to come from some browser extension.

Comment: I don't mind this being an extension of my firefox browser. However this code above does not run whether it is a firefox browser with or without extensions or a google chrome or google mobile.

The only message I have is the one indicated at the beginning of the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a conflict with another javascript function in another file that used the `window.onload = () => {}` function
to create an animation.

So I remove it.